# How to query node-html-parser path with classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

I am stuck with **node-html-parser** (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser). I read HTML into local variable and I am trying to get to the following node (JS path that is copied from Chrome):

```
#container > section > div > div.profile__main > div.item.item__profile > div.item__profile__info.cf > div.item__profile__info__data > p
```

Unfortuantely I get stuck at **div.profile__main** .
(`profile__main` is a class within div and the tag looks like `<div class="profile__main" ...></div>`

How do I query for this stuff. So far I got only here:

```
var root = this.HTMLParser.parse(this.data)
root.querySelectorAll("#container")
      .querySelectorAll("section")
      .querySelectorAll("div")
      .querySelector("div.profile__main") // Cant get this one. returns null
```

Thanks

Comment: try removing `div` from `div.profile__main`

Comment: @CodeManiac this does not work

Answer (score 2):

```
const root = this.HTMLParser.parse(this.data)
const itemProfileInfoData = root.getElementsByTagName("div").find(div => div.attributes.class === "item__profile__info__data")
itemProfileInfoData.childNodes.filter(child => child.tagName === "p")
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like

```
var root = this.HTMLParser.parse(this.data)
root.querySelectorAll(".item__profile__info__data")
      .querySelectorAll("p")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe last element, tag `<p>`, is loading async.
Please, check the "view source" of site that you parsing.